# Schauder Basis for Homeo$^+(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces, schauder-basis

In the 50's through 70's there was a lot of research into the group of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of the plane, denoted as Homeo$^+(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (in the compact-open topology, which in this case is just the topology of compact convergence).  Long proofs were used to prove certain local properties like local arc-connectedness and local contractibility.

But much more recently it was shown that Homeo$^+(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is actually a Hilbert manifold, i.e. locally homeomorphic to separable Hilbert space.  The proof was rather abstract, but it leaves open the question of whether it can just be displayed directly; it wasn't believed to be so nice back when the foundational work was being done, so I'm not sure anyone ever tried.

I guess the best way to get a direct proof is to just find the basis!

> What is an explicit orthonormal basis for a neighborhood of $id \in$ Homeo$^+(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

I've been trying to do this myself using very simple functions, but haven't been able to come up with it.  Here I don't want to *a priori* assume that the group is a Hilbert manifold, I want to prove it directly (or at least the local homeomorphism).

It seems like this is more a problem for people in functional analysis, so hopefully somebody can help!

Comment: My feeling is that there won't be a "linear" correspondence in any of the usual senses, it needs a bit more cleverness than I've got haha

Comment: Surely you should not expect there to exist any "explicit" Hamel basis, given that even just a plain old Hilbert space does not have any "explicit" Hamel basis.

Comment: I agree, this does not exist.  Much more reasonable would be: an explicit **orthonormal basis** for the tangent space at $id$ (or a **Schauder basis**).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was wading into set-theoretic stuff, I wasn't using 'explicit' in any technical sense.  Yes, I'd be satisfied with an 'explicit' Schauder basis; I'll amend the question!

Comment: What's a reference for the statement that it's a Hilbert manifold?

Comment: @LeeMosher https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010223 He gives the statement in a sort of obnoxiously general way, but it's Corollary 1.1 with $X = \varnothing$ (he specifically includes this case).  I know that Taras Banakh has worked with him, maybe has  something to say on the matter (is he still active here?).

Comment: Did you make any headway on your question by tracing through the proof of Corollary 1.1?

Comment: @LeeMosher No, that paper is basically an abstract-nonsense way of extending the more nitty-gritty proofs in the Hamstrom paper from the compact case (using a lot of Yagasaki's own work from other papers).  The Hamstrom paper itself isn't accessible, though I found a 1965 precursor paper https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1965-120-01/S0002-9947-1965-0184234-3/S0002-9947-1965-0184234-3.pdf.  The methods there are very non-explicit too, would assume the 1966 paper is the same.  All of this work is definitely in the 'retract theory' vein, with a bit of complex analysis.

Comment: Well, I would be very surprised if any new proof technique had emerged, with sufficient explicitness to let one write out a basis, other than by taking whatever abstract nonsense basis emerges from those papers.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think there should be some combinatorial-flavored one with the appropriately-selected 'little shifts' kind of thing.  I tried for a while and kept getting things that almost worked, but I just wasn't QUITE clever enough.  But I really felt like it would be possible, always seemed to be just around the corner with just one more idea or nuance.